# Invalid column name 'EmployeeStatu_Id'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework, I have a table EmployeeStatus, and it has column Id. Entity Framework make it singular to EmployeeStatu, and when I insert data in this table then it gives me this error:

```
Invalid column name 'EmployeeStatu_Id'.
```

How i can fix it without changing it to plural.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `Column` attribute to override the name of the column? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn

Comment: I am using DB First approad, Actually this singularise the EmployeeStatus table name with EmployeeStatu by removing s at the end, that's why this is creating this issue. Is there any way that EF should not singularise some tables not the all?

Comment: I have same issue as https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/539109/entity-framework-pluralization-incorrect-for-word-status

Comment: Fixed this issue, there was issue with my code, EF was considering it as code first. Please close this question.